# How extract records from a dictionary that doesn't have comma and with None values in the keys

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

This dictionary has a weird format.

- When running nested for loop, it breaks because some of the keys `'top'` and `'rising'` come with "None"
- The indexes that actually have usable data in, has some noise such text:`query value` or text numbers that are not index such as `0  1  2  3`
- Also there is no comma to separate the rows.

So the **goal is..** transform the usable part of the data into dataframe.

data:

```
d = 

{1: {'abroad': {'top': None, 'rising': None}},
 2: {'house': {'top': None, 'rising': None}},
 3: {'school': {'top':                            query  value
   0     l    100
   1     x    100
   2     y     44
   3     j     31
   4     k      6, 'rising': None}},
 4: {'in_house': {'top':                            query  value
   0            a    100
   1            b     97
   2            c     32
   3            d     12,  'rising': None}},
 5: {'community': {'top': None, 'rising':      query  value
   0            s    100}},
 }
```

my code:

```
list_words = []


for x in dicti:

    for a in dicti[x]:
        print(x, a)

        for b in dicti[x][a].values():
            print(b)
            list_words.append(b)



data = pd.DataFrame(list_words)
data = data.dropna(how='all')  
data = data.rename(columns={0:'search'})
data = data.search.astype(str)
data = data.reset_index()

data = data[0].str.split(",")
```

Desired output:

```
search     score    status
l        100      top
x        100      top
y        44       top 
j        31       top
k        6        top
a        100      top
b        97       top
c        32       top
d        12       top
s        100      rising
```

Comment: your dictionary isn't valid

Comment: Thank you guys, the answer bellow worked, great. check it out

Comment: it doesn't mean anything, just replaced the real values with random words within keeping some pattern of the problem

Comment: It will help to solve the issues by understanding the form of your data.  The weird values are dataframes `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'query': ['l', 'x'], 'value': [100, 100]})` `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'query': ['a', 'b'], 'value': [100, 97]})` `df3 = pd.DataFrame({'query': ['s'], 'value': [100]})` and `data = {1: {'abroad': {'top': None, 'rising': None}},
 2: {'house': {'top': None, 'rising': None}},
 3: {'school': {'top': df1, 'rising': None}},
 4: {'in_house': {'top': df2,  'rising': None}},
 5: {'community': {'top': None, 'rising':  df3}}}`  If you print `data`, it will look like your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `concat`:

```
pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(v).assign(status=k) for y in d.values() 
            for x in y.values() for k,v in x.items()
         )
```

Output:

```
   status query  value
0     top     l  100.0
1     top     x  100.0
2     top     y   44.0
3     top     j   31.0
4     top     k    6.0
0     top     a  100.0
1     top     b   97.0
2     top     c   32.0
3     top     d   12.0
0  rising     s  100.0
```